# passing HTML with event.currenttarget to a template literal to use it as inner HTML

Tags: javascript, html

so there is an event listener that going to give its own HTML  to the function called **aww** with event.currenttarget in order to render it again with innerHTML, I pass it  with a const called **choose** when I log the **choose**, its give the HTML correctly but  when I render the page  in its place this will  show  up   :
`[object HTMLDivElement]`  so tried to use JSON.parse on it to remove string  but it didn't work   :

```
document.querySelector(".h1").addEventListener("click",aaw)
document.querySelector(".h2").addEventListener("click",aaw)
document.querySelector(".h3").addEventListener("click",aaw)
function aaw(event) {
    const choose = event.currentTarget
    document.body.innerHTML =
        `
    <div class="container">
    ${ choose}
    <div class="monster">
        <div class="monster-up">
            <h2>mordkaiser</h2>
            <div class="outside-bar">
                <div class="inside-bar">

                </div>
            </div>
            

        </div>
        <div class="monster-down">
            <div class="dicerools">

            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>

    <button>attack</button>
</div>
    
    
    `
}
```

How can we put that `e.currenttarget` into the template literal to use it with innerHTML?

Comment: `const choose = event.currentTarget.innerHTML;`

Comment: okay will test it

Comment: Be aware that by overwriting the document body you will remove any event handlers not directly attached to `document.body`

Comment: so any event listener that isn't in HTML will be removed?  if I select another thing it will work fine?

Comment: the problem with innerHTML is this it's going to give the inner elements is there any way to get the parent as well?

Comment: Event listeners are traditionally attached once the body is initially loaded, by overriting the body the handlers are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to interpolate a node, typeof object, with a string, which will annoyingly give you `[object Object]` or in your case, `[object HTMLDivElement]`. If you want to embed the node's HTML, you can easily access it with the `innerHTML` attribute:

```js
const choose = event.currentTarget.innerHTML; // <-- Will return something like "<div>hello</div>"
```

And it will be rendered as HTML in your string interpolation.

#### Edit

If you want the HTML including its parent, simply change `innerHTML` to `outerHTML`:

```js
const choose = event.currentTarget.outerHTML; // <-- Will return something like "<div><div id="child">blah</div>helllo<button>cool</button></div>"
```

Comment: one thing to say inner HTML will only give the inner HTML what about the parent? I want  parent plus its child

Comment: Then `outerHTML` will do the trick. See my edit.